# What is the difference between a pointer and a reference variable in Java?

Tags: java

My Java book explains that to use objects, we can assign them to reference variables.  How is that different from a pointer to an object?  Does Java have pointers?

Thanks :)

Comment: you cannot talk about pointers if talking about java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference/7034719#7034719;

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer

Comment: [JLS §4.3.1: "An *object* is a *class instance* or an *array*. **The reference values (often just *references*) are pointers to these objects**, and a special null reference, which refers to no object."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A reference is sort of like a pointer that you can't do arithmetic on... although it's more opaque. While the underlying bits *may* be an address in virtual memory, they don't have to be. They're just a way of getting to an object (or representing the null value). So while they're not exactly the same, if you're used to thinking of a pointer as "a way of identifying an object or navigating to it" (in some sense) then yes, those thoughts apply to references too.

Java doesn't have pointers as such (unlike, say, C# which has references *and* pointers - the latter being used in "unsafe" code).

Comment: Is it possible that references are really pointers under the hood, just abstracted away?

Comment: @morbidCode Depends on the JVM implementation.  It doesn't _have_ to be, but can be.  Native pointers must be updated after the garbage collector has done its work.

Answer (score 16):

```
Cat x = new Cat();
```

This line creates a Cat object in memory and stores a reference to it in x.

x now contains a reference to the Cat object, but if you were to do:

```
x = x + 1;
```

This would not give the next memory address like in C, but would give a compiler error. Java doesn't allow control to the reference or memory location.

Comment: This simple example gives the most important difference.

Answer (score 14):

The terms "reference" and "pointer" are basically equivalent.  Much of the literature I've seen about the basics of Java claims that Java has no pointers.  But if you try to use a `null` reference you get a `NullPointerException`.  So it's all semantics.

(The real difference is, in C or C++ the term "pointer" strictly means an integer that happens to be the memory address of some data.  Whereas in Java the term "reference" more closely matches the C++ "reference" concept.  You can't work with the memory address directly even if you want to, but you use it the same way.)

Comment: `NullPointerException` was named very early.  A better name had been NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 4):

If we think of references or pointers as a kind of means to access or handle the object in memory, they are much the same. However, they are different in terms of implementation. Following are the differences:

1. Pointers support pointer arithmetic and this makes them a kind of unsafe. Because they provide the programmer with an access level that is much more than needed. However, references provide an handle to the object through a much more abstract hided implementation.
2. Pointers are less strongly typed and references are more strongly typed. By this I mean the code is much simple in case of references and slightly less formal in case of pointers. You need to make use of reinterpret_cast kind of things to use pointers casts and on the other hand, references support easy casts of the kind of primitive kind of casts in "C".
3. Pointers are unsafe and references are safe. If you have an option between the two select references. In languages like C#, you have this freedom.
4. Pointers exists in C/C++ and references exist in Java. Do not confuse references in C/C++ with references in Java. References in C/C++ is a kind of synonym used for the rvalue of a pointer in C/C++.

Answer (score 2):

No, Java does not have pointers. The fundamental concepts in Java are "values" vs "references".

Comment: Java has _pointers_ and calls them _references_. Java does not have "pointer arithmetic" and references are typed but are still pointers.

Comment: you're right, that's what i meant as well. Kerrek saw the same thing i did initially.

Comment: @Matteo: In what way is it useful to think in terms of "pointers" when designing Java code? I think the value/reference dichotomy is a rather more useful one: values are copied, references are aliased.

Comment: @Kerrek: I find confusing telling someone that is used to pointers, that they don't exist. If I want to implement a tree in Java I can do the same as in C, I use pointers/references to some data structures.

Comment: @Matteo: Perhaps to an experienced C++ programmer, such an explanation would be useful. In general (and we have no idea what the OP knows), I like the clean-slate, self-contained approach that works with ideas that are intrinsic to the language and don't introduce an additional burden. It's a matter of taste, I suppose, but it's good to maintain a distinction of what's part of the *language* and what is merely a good analogy or implementation.

Comment: The JLS actually says they are pointers, so it's not correct to say Java doesn't have pointers. ["The reference values (often just *references*) are pointers to these objects, \[...\]."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

A reference is a pointer that you can't normally see the *value* of (i.e., the memory address). The only operations allowed are to set it (from another reference) and to reference through it to the referred-to object.  It can be set from a reference-valued expression, such as the *new* operator, or from another reference (which is syntactically a simple reference-valued expression).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Java syntax - it's true, that Java doesn't have pointers, but to  clarify situation - **Java Runtime** **has** pointers.
Every time **GC** occurs, there is a big chance, that your object stored in the **heap** will physically change it's memory address. This is achievable only by using what is really called **Pointer**. As you come from `C++` world - you know reference restrictions. But it doesn't mean that JVM doesn't use references =).

For further information take a look at [Ordinary Object Pointer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html)

So, as you have brief understanding of core JVM memory management, you can consider **Java Reference** term as **Pointer** at runtime.

No, there is no **pass by reference** at all. Only pass by value, since the real Java method argument is a copy of **Java Reference**, therefore - another **Pointer**.

So, in syntax usage way - **Java Reference** is closer to **C++ Reference**, but in real Runtime world it's close to **Pointer**.

P.s. for more clarification it's better to read more articles about **Ordinary Object Pointer** or take a loot at **oop.hpp**.

Answer (score 0):

As Java does not support pointers. It may appear that references are special kind of pointers. But we must note the key difference: with a pointer, we can point any address (which is actually a number slot in a memory). So, it is quite possible that with a pointer, we can point an invalid address also and then we may face surprises issues during runtime. But reference types will always
point to valid addresses or they will point to null.

Answer (score -2):

pointer only contain the address but Reference does not contains address if we say frankly then 
address of the object is assigned to the index or we say can hash code and case code is given to the reference variable if we will see the content of the reference variable it starts with class Name @ and after it some Hexadecimal Code. These nos are not address it is a index value or hash code.

second point 
we can not perform any Arithmetic operations  on values the Content of reference value