# Do Java create new String or pointer to orignal String?

Tags: java

I wonder if Java ever creates pointers to an other String.

One example where it could be a pointer:

```
App app = new App("name");
String name = app.getName();
```

If I after `String name` is initialized change the value with `app.setName("newName")`, `String name`'s value won't change.
This suggests that String name isn't a pointer but a new String.

But it could be, right? I mean it could be a pointer until either of the values (String name in App or String name) is changed to save memory?

So is it ever a pointer?

Not the same question as: [String Interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-internin%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bg)
Which specifically asks for explanation of String Interning. e.g String.intern()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is String interning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning)

Comment: It's always a pointer, but String objects are immutable

Comment: also as you are asking for pointer: [is java "pass-by-value" or "pass-by-reference"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: it's always a **reference** which you can think of as a *pointer* for simplicity, but it isn't.

Comment: @KevinEsche how is this question the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-string-interning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All references to objects are pointers; however, `setName` will change the value of the pointer, i.e., point it to somewhere else. Also, note that Strings are immutable and internalized, so there is always one instance per value and they never change.

Comment: *"All references to objects are pointers"* no, they are not, because **Java has no pointers**. You can for simplicity handle references  like pointers but they aren't none.

Comment: o'rly Java has no pointers ? then a reference linked to some data in memory is not a pointer ??? The only difference from the C/C++ native pointers , is that you cannot perform arithmetic operations in order to loop or change where the pointer looks

Comment: @TimothyTruckle java doesn't have manually managed pointers like C (thankfully), but the references it holds work just like pointers: they are a reference to a specific place in memory. So in `Person a = new Person(), b = a;`, both a and b "point" to the same location in memory, so changes made inside person a will reflect on b and vice-versa.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436581/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pointer-and-a-reference-variable-in-java

Comment: @AntJavaDev *"The only difference from the C/C++ native pointers , is that you cannot perform arithmetic operations"* references are updated if the garbage collector moves the objecs in memory, with pointers you can't do that eiher.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle so the native implementation of Java's GC is not using any pointers at all or the `ArrayCopy` commands , sure bro

Comment: @AntJavaDev *"the native implementation of Java's GC is not using any pointers at all"* the *native implementation* is not part of the Java language. It's just something that happens under the hood.

Comment: yeap but you pointed out that native pointers cannot move objects in memory ..... does the pointer knows about objects ..... sure bro :)

Comment: To find out whether a reference is a pointer, we need to know what the words "reference" and "pointer" mean. The meanings of those words can be different in different contexts. A "reference" in Java is different from a "reference" in C++, for example (the latter cannot be null). The Java spec does (to my knowledge) not define what a pointer is, but it does contain the following sentence: "The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object." So, yes, a (non-null) reference is a pointer (but it's not a C++ pointer).

Comment: "so there is always one instance per value" - if you mean that two `"asdf"` strings will always be the same object, then no, that's completely wrong. Not all strings are interned. (Also, the term is "interned", not "internalized".)

Answer (score 3):

app.setName("newName") will create a new String "newName" and store it in the String pool, the String pointer in app is now replaced to point at the new String. The "name" String still exists.

The key thing to remember is Java string objects **never** change, if you create a new String, or modify an old one, it always results in the creation of a new object. Also, String is an object, so String variables always store references to a String stored elsewhere (in the heap with your other variables, or in the String constant pool).